# Sending email notification upon error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set up this try/catch and I want to send an error to my email when something goes wrong like an invalid password being entered.   I know I have most of it right but I'm not getting an email when I force a change in my config file.  I'm not getting any errors when I run this so I'm assuming it must be something small.  Does anyone see any obvious errors I've made?  Let me know if additional info is required.

Thanks in advance...learning tons of C# but no master just yet.

```
try
            {
                _arrivals = new ArrivalsService();

                _configuration = new Configuration(xmlMessage);

                //process summary or detail
                if (_configuration.IncludeHODetails == true)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Include HOH Details is a future feature.");

                    //ProcessArrivalDetails(_configuration);
                }
                else
                    ProcessArrivalSummary(_configuration);

                UpdateLastRunDate(_configuration.ClientId, _configuration.LastRunDateId, DateTime.Now);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (_configuration == null)
                {
                    string[] messageTo = new[] { "aaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com" };
                    //string acctManagerEmail = Util.usp_GetEmailAcct(_clientId);
                    //string[] messageTo = new[] { "77777777777.com", acctManagerEmail };


                    EmailUtility.SendEmail(Util.EMAIL_FROM, messageTo,
            "Error Running Report Utility for Client: " + _configuration.DbName, "Error Message: " + ex.Message,
            Util.SMTP_SERVER, false);
                }
                throw new Exception("Error Occurred");
                
            }
```

Here's my EmailUtility file:

```
namespace Common
{
    public class EmailUtility
    {
        public static string SMTP_SERVER;

        public static string[] GetEmailRecipientAdmin();
        public static void SendEmail(string messageFrom, string[] messageTo, string messageSubject, string messageBody, string ipAddress, bool isHtml);
        public static void SendEmail(string messageFrom, string[] messageTo, string[] messageCC, string messageSubject, string messageBody, string messageAttachmentPath, string ipAddress, bool isHtml);
        public static void SendEmail(string messageFrom, string[] messageTo, string[] messageCC, string messageSubject, string messageBody, string[] messageAttachmentPath, string ipAddress, bool isHtml);
        public static void SendEmail(string messageFrom, string messageTo, string messageSubject, string messageBody, string ipAddress, bool isHtml);
        public static void SendEmail(string messageFrom, string messageTo, string messageSubject, string messageBody, string messageAttachmentPath, string ipAddress, bool isHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `EmailUtility.SendEmail`? Is there a guide you're following along with?

Comment: I suggest you start with just sending an email _every time the program starts_ and debug through your program to see what it is doing.

Comment: Is an exception actually caught? Is `_configuration` not null? Please share the contents of `EmailUtility.SendEmail`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary added the EmailUtility file.  I made the _configuration == null and it actually threw an exception so i think thats a step in the right direction.

Comment: You need to provide a fully reproducible example according to the stackoverflow guidelines